# Getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays

I have this code :

```
public class OddSum1 {
   public OddSum1() {
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   int OddLimit = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
   int sum = 0;

   for (int i = 1; i <= OddLimit; i += 2) {
     sum += i;
   }

   System.out.println("The sum of odd numbers from 1 to " + OddLimit + " is " + sum);

   }    
}
```

Whenever I run it I get this error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at OddSum1.main(OddSum1.java:7)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

It's supposed to prompt user for a number and then sums the odd number from 1 to the number entered, I'm guessing it's a problem with this `int OddLimit = Integer.parseInt(args[0])`;

but I just don't know how to fix it, any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take either of the two approaches from below :

Approach 1 : You can specify the oddLimit by passing it as an argument to the main method as :

Code :

```
public class OddSum1 {
public OddSum1() {
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
int OddLimit = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= OddLimit; i += 2)
sum += i;
System.out.println("The sum of odd numbers from 1 to " + OddLimit + " is " + sum);
}    
}
```

To compile and run the code :

`javac OddSum1.java`

`java OddSum1 20`

Approach 2 : Read the OddLimit interactively from the prompt

Code:

```
public class OddSum1 {
public OddSum1() {
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

int OddLimit = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= OddLimit; i += 2)
sum += i;

System.out.println("The sum of odd numbers from 1 to " + OddLimit + " is " + sum);

}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> It's supposed to prompt user for a

You need to pass arguments to main, Command line argument and then change index to `0`

for example:

```
$java YourMainClass 5
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not prompt you for input. You will have to add the input to the command line.

```
java OddSum1 5
```

Comment: Or he can rewrite the project to take the input from the `java.io.Console` class. or he can do both, testing first on `args.length`, then working from the console.

Answer (score 0):

Your array `args` is empty.

```
int OddLimit = Integer.parseInt("100");
```

hardcode number, or pass it from command line

Answer (score 0):

If using Eclipse, choose from the top menu Run->Run... and under the Arguments tab provide a number for the Program arguments.